# Recyclerview with 2 layouts from objects inside other object

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a list of objects with a list of objects inside each.
for each object I would like to make 2 different layoutet rows in a recyclerView.
one layout with a string directly from the object and following another layout for each item in the list from the object

*Pseudo code*

Object main: string name,list records;

Object record: String game, int record;

*Output:*

main(0).name - (layout 1)

main(0).record(0).game - (layout 2)

main(0).record(1).game - (layout 2)

main(1).name - (layout 1)

main(1).record(0) - (layout 2)

main(1).record(1) - (layout 2)

I can do it with one object, but cannot get the logic right when I have 2 or more main objects.

Code:

```
    @Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    switch(viewType){
        case 0:{
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_1, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(v);
            break;
        }
        case 1:{
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_2, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolderTo(v);
            break;
        }
    }
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {


        switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
            case 0: {
                model = mList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                MyViewHolder viewHolder = (MyViewHolder) holder;
                viewHolder.name.setText(model.getName());
                break;
            }
            case 1: {
                ViewHolderTo viewholder = (ViewHolderTo) holder;
                viewholder.ting.setText(model.getRecords().get(position-1).getGame());
                break;
            }
        }
    }

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    int tmp;

    if(position==0||position==3||position==6){
         return 0;
    } else{
        return 1;
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    int count = 0;
    for(MyListModel item: mList){
        count += item.getRecords().size();
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Hopefully there are some sharper brains in here :-)
Please let me know if you need more code

Working code. *Thx to Luksprog*

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    switch(viewType){
        case 0:{
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_1, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(v);
            break;
        }
        case 1:{
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_2, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolderTo(v);
            break;
        }
    }
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    int[] pos = mapToRealPositions(position);
    model = mList.get(pos[0]);

    switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
        case 0: {
            MyViewHolder viewHolder = (MyViewHolder) holder;
            viewHolder.name.setText(model.getName());
            break;
        }
        case 1: {
            ViewHolderTo viewholder = (ViewHolderTo) holder;
            viewholder.ting.setText(model.getRecords().get(pos[1]).getGame());
            break;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    int tmp;

    if(position==0||position==3||position==21){
        return 0;
    } else{
        return 1;
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    int count = 0;
    for(MyListModel item: mList){
        count += item.getRecords().size();
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

// this method will return an int array with two values, first value will be the position of the main item in mList, the second
// value will be the position of the child(in the records list) in the maim item
public int[] mapToRealPositions(int recyclerPos) {
    int reference = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < mList.size(); i ++) {
        final int childNr = mList.get(i).getRecords().size();
        if (recyclerPos < reference + 1 + childNr) {
            return new int[]{i, recyclerPos - reference - 1};
        } else {
            reference += 1 + childNr;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: can you share the screen shot? how you want the layouts in Recycler view?

Comment: Only with one object. Pretend the 3 lines with a different name below :-)

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw6_BwSSLrvhOFNueXpZUVBjeHYwYzhtNjJmd2VKTEVNMXdZ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The problem is the the first line is from main-object and the 2. and 3. line are from a list of objects inside main-object.
Next 3 lines would also be main-object and 2.-3. line from list in main-object.

Comment: In your adapter you should have a method to translate the "expanded" position used by the recycler into a position relative to mList(which you use to extract the model from mList), something like this: public int getDataPosition(int recyclerPos) {
  int reference = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < mList.size(); i ++){
   int childNr = mList.get(i).getRecords();
   if (recyclerPos <= reference + 1 + childNr) {
    return i;
   } else {
    reference += 1 + childNr;   
   }
  }
    } . You could then use: model = mList.get(getDataPosition(position)); in onBindViewHolder().

Comment: It worked :-)
Thank for your help, Luksprog

I will update the question with the working code for the next confused soul who stumble by ;-)

Comment: I was to fast in the last comment :-(
It has all the elements, but the ordering is wrong. 
See linked image
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1ydUmwmLYtxc3ozdGVZN3EyZUE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: That gives me an 
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 2
in line 
    int childNr = mList.get(recyclerPos).getRecords().size();

Comment: I didn't look at your code too thorough, you can't use the same method call for getting both the item position and the record position. I've made a small gist with some changes that should solve the problem. You can find it here https://gist.github.com/luksprog/3e6b938a447283cc1837f9035da54433

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I was running in a completely wrong direction :-)